# get values from an object and set checkboxes state

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

in the example below I need the first checkbox to be `checked` and the second and third to be `unchecked`

currently I'm getting all of them `checked`

```js
let data = {"admin":"true","nts":"false","chat":"false"};

$('button').on('click', function(){
    $('.bcheck').each(function(){
            let x = $(this).attr('data-x');
            $(this).attr('checked', data[x]);
        });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type='checkbox' class='bcheck' data-x='admin'>
<input type='checkbox' class='bcheck' data-x='nts'>
<input type='checkbox' class='bcheck' data-x='chat'>
<button>CLICK</button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The string `"false"` is not falsy (try `!!"false" === true` in the console). Can you change the strings to regular booleans (`false`)?

EDIT this should do it:

```
let transformedData = {};

const dataEntries = Object.entries(data).map((entry) => {
  return { [entry[0]]: !(entry[1] === "false") };
});

for (const entry of dataEntries) {
  transformedData = { ...transformedData, ...entry };
}
```

Comment: in fact I'm getting the `data` from an ajax call, so the values are with quotes. How to remove the quotes from values in a resulting object?

Comment: you could write a function that maps `"false"` to `false`: `const convertStringToBool = (value) => !(value === "false")` and loop through `Object.values(data)`, running `convertStringToBool` on each value. of course that only works if you only expect `"true"` or `"false"` -- you might need to handle other cases

Comment: i edited my answer, let me know if that works for you

Answer (score 2):

Your values in the `data` object are all strings. So they will all evaluate to `true`. Lose the strings and make them booleans.

```js
let data = {
  "admin": true,
  "nts": false,
  "chat": false
};

$('button').on('click', function() {
  $('.bcheck').each(function() {
    let x = $(this).attr('data-x');
    console.log(data[x]);
    $(this).attr('checked', data[x]);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type='checkbox' class='bcheck' data-x='admin'>
<input type='checkbox' class='bcheck' data-x='nts'>
<input type='checkbox' class='bcheck' data-x='chat'>
<button>CLICK</button>
```

Comment: in fact I'm getting the `data` from an ajax call, so the values are with quotes. How to remove the quotes from values in a resulting object?